# VueJS mustache undefined constant

Tags: laravel, vue.js, laravel-blade, mustache

I was trying to make VueJS work with Laravel and something odd is happening.

My template:

```
<div id="tuto">
  <p>{{ texte }}</p>
</div>
```

My VueJS script:

```
var vm = new Vue({
    el: '#tuto',
    data: {
        texte: '<span>Mon texte</span>',
    }
});
```

I am getting this error:

> Use of undefined constant texte - assumed 'texte' (View: /var/www/vhosts/xxxx/resources/views/admin/xxx/index.blade.php)

[Full error here.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rMm7G.png)

Does someone know where it's messing up?

Thank's

Comment: Consider separating your logic in a [single Vue file](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/single-file-components.html).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you are using a `.blade.php` file then you need to do:

```
<div id="tuto">
  <p>@{{ texte }}</p>
</div>
```

That's because blade also uses mustaches, so they get processed by blade before vue even sees them, which is why you are receiving an error from `Laravel` and not from `Vue`.

See the [Blade & JavaScript Frameworks section](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/blade#displaying-data) of the Laravel docs for more details.

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways going about that.

1: Use the `@` before the mustaches.

Example:

`@{{ texte }}`

---

2: The other one is to use the `@verbatim` directive over a code block.

Example:

```
@verbatim
    {{ texte }}
@endverbatim
```

https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/blade#blade-and-javascript-frameworks

Answer (score -1):

`data` [must be](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#data-Must-Be-a-Function) a function:

```
var vm = new Vue({
    el: '#tuto',
    data: function(){
        return {
            texte: '<span>Mon texte</span>'
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: data must be a function for component instances, he is not using any components https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#data-Must-Be-a-Function